# Hiding UIView animation in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitextfield

I am trying to hide/present UITextField with an animation. The animation works when presenting the text field but not when hiding, is there any particular reason for this?

```
UIView.transition(with: self.confirmPasswordTextField, duration: 0.5, options: [.transitionCrossDissolve], animations: {
            self.confirmPasswordTextField.isHidden = self.login
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
 })
```

Answer (score 2):

You better use `alpha`

```
self.confirmPasswordTextField.alpha = show ? 0.0 : 1.0
UIView.transition(with: self.confirmPasswordTextField, duration: 0.5, options: [.transitionCrossDissolve], animations: {
    self.confirmPasswordTextField.alpha = show ? 1.0 : 0.0
})
```